# Why is SetTarget a static method of Storyboard

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I wonder about one of details in MS class (Storyboard) and related class - Timeline.

Here are docs for those classes:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline(v=vs.110).aspx

According to MS documentation to set a Target on Timeline, we need to use Storyboard static method. Why is that so? Does anyone know the background of this decision?

Where is the information about Timeline target stored? In Storyboard static fields? In Storyboard object being Timeline parent? In private fields of Timeline?

Thanks if advance if you have any information about this implementation as I wonder if there is a reason why they took this course of actions.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Media/Animation/Storyboard.cs,81222d8a2eaf2532,references

Comment: *Target* is an attached property, the getter and setter for it must always be static.  MSDN page [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#custom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of static methods threw me at first when I encountered Silverlight/WPF. The data is actually stored on the Timeline, and not elsewhere, but why static methods, and not just methods on the Timeline object itself?

The reason is this: most WPF/Silverlight elements have a lot of properties: backgrounds, fonts, stroke thicknesses, etc. If they were implemented the conventional way, these will consume a lot of memory.

Instead, Silverlight/WPF introduces the idea of DependencyProperties. These are properties that can be set on DepedencyObject. If you don't set them, you will get the default value, and no additional memory is used. `SetValue(ThePropertyName, value)` and `GetValue(ThePropertyName)` are typically used to set and retrieve dependency property values.

In addition, there is an idea called AttachedProperty. Attached properties are properties that are defined by third party, and can be *attached* to a DependencyObject. This is similar to the property extenders in Visual Basic. It allows additional properties to be defined against existing elements. Storyboard animation is implemented this way.